# how to save a local copy of xml being output by certain website

Tags: php

I want to save a local copy of xml being ouput by a certain website, and everytime I changed the URL of a website to get another copy of xml it will overwrite the file that saved from previous website, how can I do this in php?

Comment: You should elaborate more on your question and if you already have code that isn't doing what you want you should show a small part of that code so we can help.  Short questions like this without detail will get down voted.  If you want people to spend their time to help you you have to spend your time to ask a detailed question.

Comment: m sorry for that.. Actually the URL is not a xml file it is a php file that generates an xml file. <code> http://example.com/generating_xml_file.php</code> how can i read the xml generated by that script and save that as an xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://example.com/file.xml');
file_put_contents('file.xml', $xml);
```

Comment: Im sorry for that.. Actually the URL is not a xml file it is a php file that generates an xml file.

http://example.com/generating_xml_file.php
how can i read the xml generated by that script and save that as an xml?

Comment: Just replace the url with the one you want. There's nothing special about that code, it will simply save any url to 'file.xml'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Is there a problem using that script if the generated xml of the URL is so huge about 50MB?

Here's my code please take a look tell me if it is okay.

```
$url = "http://projects.com/read.php";
$fp = fopen($url, 'r'); 
if ($fp) {
    while (!feof($fp))
        $buffer .= fgets($fp, 1024);
    fclose($fp);
    file_put_contents('file.xml', $buffer);
} else {
    echo 'Could not connect to: ' . htmlentities($url) . '<br />';
    echo 'Error #' . $err_num.': ' . $err_msg;
    exit;
}
```